# How to make SignalR subscribing to a Redis channel?

Tags: .net, redis, signalr

I have a Java server performing some work and publishing its results on Redis. I want to send this results in realtime to some users; so I implemented a solution based on SignalR. The results have to be available for a lot of clients, and SignalR is only one of them; so the server can't be modified to fit exactly what I want. Basically, here is what I have :

Server -> Redis -> SignalR -> Browser

I think it's an ugly solution, as it uses a Lazy type to listen to the subscribed channel and call a delegate to tell SignalR to push data. The best solution would have been to push data directly from the server to signalr, but I can't change the way the server publishes its results. I thought of an executable acting as a bridge between Redis and Signalr, but it seems even more ugly :(

Is there another way to make SignalR listening to a Redis channel ?

Comment: I'm facing same issue, having two projects, web and api, wanted to use SignalR but not sure how to read messages from Redis. Did you solve this issue? Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/60052889/4753489

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis` library made available by Microsoft.

The configuration is minimal. All you have to do is:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("server", port, "password", "AppName");
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

[Here is the link to the documentation.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis)

Basically, what it does is creates a pub/sub channel on your Redis instance which it will use. (Be careful if the Redis instance is part of a cluster!The messages it will bounce between all instances, resulting in the client receiving tens of thousands of messages!)

Under the hood, it will replace the standard Message Bus of SignalR with an implementation of Message Bus that will put the messages in the Redis pipeline.

Hope this helps!

Best of luck!

Comment: This is for a SignalR scaleout, which is not my actual problem; the server I am talking about is a Java server which communicate with others clients, and SignalR is only one of them; so the server can't be modified to fit exactly SignalR. I'll try to make my question more clear.

Comment: I don't see how you configure the channel here