# Communicate web app and api project using SignalR & StackExchangeRedis

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm working with a project built with ASP.NET Core 2.2. The main solution contains multiple projects, which includes API, web and other class libraries.

We've used SignalR to displaying shared messages/notifications between the API project and the web project. For example, adding a new employee record from an API should call SignalR Hub and all the web client should received the notification.

To make it communicate, we have used Radis with SignalR

```
// SignalR Configuration
services.AddSignalR(option =>
{
    option.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    option.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
}).AddStackExchangeRedis(options =>
{
    options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "TestChannel";
    options.Configuration.EndPoints.Add("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    options.Configuration.ClientName = "ClientNameSignalR";
    options.Configuration.AllowAdmin = true;
});
```

When I try to get client list in Radis,

[image]

Now, how to sending and receiving messages from web app and API?

Answer (score 0):

The code you share is used to [set up a Redis backplane for scaling out your ASP.NET Core SignalR app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

> how to sending and receiving messages from web app and API?

To achieve above requirement, you can do:

For your API project and [Hub server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1), you can inject an instance of IHubContext in your API controller, then you can access to an instance of IHubContext in controller action and push message/notification to client(s).

- [Access a SignalR IHubContext to send notifications to clients from outside a hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

For your web app, you can built and implement SignalR JavaScript client functionality to receive notifications.

- [SignalR JavaScript client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1)